# Селектор, который выбирает элемента впереди себя

Tags: html, css

Имеется селектор A~B {style} - селектор обобщённых родственных элементов, который меняет элемент B если впереди него есть селектор A. Как сделать обратный селектор, который меняет селектор А, если после него есть селектор B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению только при помощи JavaScript, с помощью CSS это никак нельзя сделать((